# get_page_by_title with an apostrophe in variable

Tags: php, shortcode, title

I'm having some trouble creating a shortcode that queries some posts. This is the basics of my code:

```
function shortcode_equipment($atts, $content = null) {

   $equipment = get_page_by_title($content, OBJECT, 'equipment');

   $loop = new WP_Query( array(
   'posts_per_page'    => 1,
   'post_type'         => 'equipment',
   'page_id'         => $equipment->ID
    ) );

   while( $loop->have_posts() ) { $loop->the_post();

   *misc code*

   wp_reset_postdata();
     return $string;
   }

}

add_shortcode( 'item', 'shortcode_equipment' );
```

Now, ordinarily, this works fine for 99% of my posts. It queries the post by what's written inside the [item]title goes here[/item] shortcode and then displays a custom tooltip/hover effect accordingly.

However, if my post title has an apostrophe in it (ex: Mal's Post), then it's breaking and just querying whatever the last post in that custom post type is.

So, how do I get this to work with apostrophes in the post titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Title `Hello world!@#$%^*(),.;:\` will work but any title you enter containing `' " < > &` characters won't work because in `$content` variable you have escaped [HTML entities](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.htmlentities.php) so Mal's Post becomes `Mal&#8217;s Post`.

To bypass it you can use [`sanitize_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) function along with [`get_page_by_path`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path).

```
function shortcode_equipment($atts, $content = null) {
   $path = sanitize_title($content);

   $equipment = get_page_by_path( $path, OBJECT, 'equipment');
```

Rest of code works as before.

Answer (score 1):

There's most likely an escaping issue happening there. Try to escape the title before passing it to your shortcode, by using `sanitize_title_for_query()`, `sanitize_title()` or even `esc_html()`:

```
$content   = sanitize_title_for_query( $content );
$equipment = get_page_by_title( $content, OBJECT, 'equipment' );
```

More information about escaping data can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data).